# Help with $base URL path in settings.php

Tags: 7, uri, configuration

Since I created my site (long time ago!) I have added content and changed many settings. My URL has always been www.domain.com/'drupalfolder'/(content)

I want to remove the drupal folder from the URL and just have my domain name (www.domain.com/content)

I have moved (manually) all the contents of the drupal folder on the 'public' folder but when I try and log in I get **not found page** or **access denied**.
I have tried to clear the caches before and after but still nothing. I had to change the main menu urls manually... I want all the URLs to change automatically!

Am I doing it properly? is there a process I can follow to save me time?

**UPDATE: I do not have access to the .htaccess file as only my host has access to it ---- I am using cPanel**

Comment: What is the base URL you have set in settings.php? What is the root you have set in .htaccess?

Comment: I'd wager that your site uses Drupal's default .htaccess. However, did you update your settings.php to reflect your new base path? `# $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';` If you moved your drupal root dir to your shared host's root directory, you should be able to comment out that line. You do so by adding a '#' at the beginning of that line.

Answer (score 0):

All URL will be changed automatically, if u have not provide static URL in it. For further checking what is causing the issue, check your apache log (if your server is Apache2)

```
cd /var/log/apache2
tail -100 error.log
```

See the latest error which is showing, or paste it here.

Comment: I am getting a [authz_core:error] [pid 32319] AH01630: client denied by server configuration in the cPanel server log